# How can I download files from streaming sites?

Tags: web, youtube, streaming

I'm trying to download files from streaming sites like youtube, soundcloud, etc. I'm aware of tools that exist like youtube-dl, but I'd like to learn how it is done myself.

I've tried looking through chrome inspector to try and find out how the sites work, but I get lost. I've tried looking through the source of youtube-dl, but I get lost there as well.

So, I guess my questions are...

- What topics should I brush up on before attempting to write my own tool?
- How do tools like youtube-dl download files from streaming sites?

Comment: As far as I know these sites encrypt their data so that simply downloading it won't work. So, making such a downloader is usually very complicated, and checking how those sites do it is impossible because the data processing is done on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

"What topics should I brush up on before attempting to write my own tool?"
**- Sorry, I don't know O.o**

"How do tools like youtube-dl download files from streaming sites?"

**YouTube download websites** determine the location of the FLV file that is served through the YouTube player. It essentially reverse engineers the Java (and now HTML5) that serves the video and gets the source.

It then prompts your browser to start downloading that FLV file, or it converts it in the cloud for you to download in the format you want. All of this is being done with VBScript or Visual Basic and Java.